# How to call R's Graphics.dll in Python?

Tags: r, python-3.x, dll, graphics

I am trying to replicate R's hist outputs in Python but R's code on hist is not visible. R is using Graphics dll file where hist function is present. I want to know how can i call R's Graphics.dll in python for hist function.
It would be great if someone can provide an example.
Regards,
gaurang

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: In R: a= seq(1,30,1)
b=hist(a)
b$breaks
[1]  0  5 10 15 20 25 30
> b$counts
[1] 5 5 5 5 5 5
> b$density
[1] 0.03333333 0.03333333 0.03333333 0.03333333 0.03333333 0.03333333
> b$mids
[1]  2.5  7.5 12.5 17.5 22.5 27.5 This hist function calls a hidden function libraries for which code is not visible in R becuase it is hidden inside a graphics.dll file. I am trying to replicate this in python since python's hist function output is not same as R's. The shortest way i could think was if there was way to call graphics.dll in python and use hist function.